# Unable to fetch image from Picasso

Tags: android

I am using Picasso to fetch my image into Listview. Then i use getIntent() to get all the particular data to another page. I am  able to get all the data but it show error in the image part :

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://fypestem.com/lecturer/com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable@52a285
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
```

Although the error is clear, but I dunno other way to change com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable@52a285 because it should be upload/image.jpg. This is my code:

```
    public class lecturer_details_modify extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

        private static final String TAG_ID="lecID";
        private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
        String lecID,lecName,lecPass,lecEmail,lecImage;
        TextView tvLecturer_modify1;
        EditText etLecturer_modify1,etLecturer_modify2,etLecturer_modify3;
        ImageView ivLecturer_modify1;

        private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

        private Bitmap bitmap;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecturer_details_modify);
            findViewById();
            Intent i=getIntent();
            lecID=i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
            lecImage=i.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGE);

                @Override
                            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                                String add="http://fypestem.com/lecturer/" +lecImage;
                                URL url=null;
                                Bitmap image=null;
                                try {
                                    url = new URL(add);
                                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return image;
                            }
                        }
                        GetImage gi=new GetImage();
                        gi.execute(lecImage);
                    }
```

Comment: Please show the part where you are calling `putExtra`. Looks like something might be wrong there.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my code.

Comment: where you are using Picasso?

Comment: CustomListAdapter class. @Nouman CH
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lec_Image);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://fystem.com/upload/"+lecturer.getImage()).into(imageView);

Comment: before doing this Picaso.with(context).load(xyz).into(imageView); try Log.i("Test","value of image is "+lecturer.getImage());

Comment: this will verify whether you are using valid imageurl or not.

Comment: can print the value of `getIntent` in `Logcat`

Comment: I/Test: value of image is 19cb18547031800eacada887edb7f02e.jpg .

Yes, it should be this, but it show com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable@52a285. This is what I am aaking for solution. How to change upload/com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable@52a285 to 19cb18547031800eacada887edb7f02e.jpg  @Nouman Ch

Comment: share the code of CustomListAdapter class

Comment: The error should be at my doInbackground if not mistaken.

Comment: could you please share how you are passing data to your listview ? share the complete code for ``CustomListAdapter ``.

Comment: Updated @SumitJha

Comment: see my answer @Kleorence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // PASS THIS WAY
                String lec_Image="fystem.com/lecturer/"+lecturers.get(position).get‌​Image();
                String lec_ID=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lec_ID)).getText().toString();

                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),lecturer_details_modify.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_IMAGE,lec_Image);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME,lec_Name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID,lec_ID);
                startActivity(in);
```

Comment: pass your lec_image as I mentioned above.

Comment: Still error, :( I have updated my code calling putExtra above.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- you have to implement like this
- make sure your url is valid and you not putting value like  this or empty `""` due to this reason it does'nt response may be it gives you `crash`

---

```
Picasso.with("Pass_Your_Context_Activity")
.load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
.placeholder(Your Drawable Resource) //this is optional the image to display while the url image is downloading
.error(Your Drawable Resource)         //this is also optional if some error has occurred in downloading the image this image would be displayed
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this kind of error is you image path is not correct according to your logs you get 
`19cb18547031800eacada887edb7f02e.jpg` and your `base url` for image is `fystem.com/upload/` by combining these both the complete strings the path become

`http://fystem.com/upload/19cb18547031800eacada887edb7f02e.jpg`
and unfortunately there is no image located on this path you can test it on browser.

hope this will help you.